# Node.js HTTP and TCP Clients Connection

Tags: javascript, vb.net, node.js, sockets, http

I am trying to create a system where I have a desktop client created in VB, and a browser based client, that can send messages to each other. I am using a Node.js server to handle the connections and messages.

This is the code of my Node.js server:

```
    net = require('net')

// Supports multiple client chat application

// Keep a pool of sockets ready for everyone
// Avoid dead sockets by responding to the 'end' event
var sockets = [];

// Create a TCP socket listener
var s = net.Server(function (socket) {

    // Add the new client socket connection to the array of
    // sockets
    sockets.push(socket);

    // 'data' is an event that means that a message was just sent by the 
    // client application
    socket.on('data', function (msg_sent) {
        // Loop through all of our sockets and send the data
        for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
            // Don't send the data back to the original sender
            if (sockets[i] == socket) // don't send the message to yourself
                continue;
            // Write the msg sent by chat client
            sockets[i].write(msg_sent);
        }
    });
    // Use splice to get rid of the socket that is ending.
    // The 'end' event means tcp client has disconnected.
    socket.on('end', function () {
        var i = sockets.indexOf(socket);
        sockets.splice(i, 1);
    });


});

s.listen(8000);
console.log('System waiting at http://localhost:8000');
```

With this sever, I am able to send messages between two desktop clients successfully.
However, because I am using net and not HTTP I cannot get the browser based client to connect.

How can I get both the clients to connect? I would really appreciate any help/suggestions/directions. I have been searching everywhere for about 4 days now! TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You could use http or express for browser based client. could check socket.io also which works on http port.

I would try to help more if know type of the desktop client you are using.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I solved the problem by creating two ports, 1 for the http connection and the 2nd for the tcp connection. And then on the message event I pass the message from the http port to the TCP port